# Opening a Modal from right icon in header -React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-modal

I need to open a modal through the right button in the header and I am able to do it.The problem is The modal should be 3/4 of the page's width and the rest 1/4 of the previous page should be visible.

StackNavigator code is below

```
FilterOptions: {
  screen: FilterOptions,
  transparentCard: true,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerMode: "none",
    header: null,
    modal: "modal",
    transparentCard: true,
  }, cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

FilterOptions Page code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

class ModalExample extends Component {

render() {
    return (

        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>

            <View style={{ height: "100%", width: '70%', backgroundColor: "#fff", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Text>Testing a modal with transparent background</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

    );
}
}
export default ModalExample
```

Can anyone help to do this.

Comment: is this what you're trying to do ? [link](https://snack.expo.io/Hk4epzQZr)

Comment: yes..Same,but I need the modal to open through button in header.Thank you :-)

Comment: you can just add the header in.. and you're welcome :-)

Comment: yeah..implemented ..saved my time

Answer (score 0):

you use react-navigation or react-native navigation ?

you do not have to use a StackNavigator

you can use react-native {Animated}

Comment: Iam using react navigation

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html#creating-a-modal-stack) for this? If yes, you can change your modal size by setting it's container size directly.

If you have some trouble with React Navigation's Modal, i suggest you use [React-Native's one](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal), as it is best used when not in full span.

Comment: This is for opening modal through a button click ,but I need a page to open as modal

Comment: Can't you change your modal view container size ?